# NoMethodError for new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple scenario that is causing me grief:

**SMSVerificationsController**

```
class SmsVerificationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

**Route**

```
  get 'sms_verifications/new'
```

**Erb**

```
link_to sms_verifications_new_path
```

All of the above are straight forward however the link is returning the following error:

```
NoMethodError in SmsVerificationsController#new
undefined method `has_content_type?' for nil:NilClass
```

The error also show the following code:

```
  # Checks if we should perform parameters wrapping.
  def _wrapper_enabled?
    return false unless request.has_content_type?

    ref = request.content_mime_type.ref
    _wrapper_formats.include?(ref) && _wrapper_key && 
    !request.request_parameters[_wrapper_key]

actionpack (5.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:283:in `_wrapper_enabled?'
```

Comment: You don't have any code in `new`?

Comment: I've stripped it back to try and identify the cause.

Comment: Please provide backtrace an code inside new method

Comment: Can you show the complete controller code?

Comment: Gerry, I had a 2nd controller function called "request" to request an SMS... looks like this word is a no go. I changed it to sms_request and now the error has gone. Thanks :)